Can't register custom event in form type with event listener
I created an autocomplete formType and I want to trigger an event when user is searching but I can't catch it with event listener (not subscriber)
When user is typing, an ajax request call searchController to dispatch the event
//customEvent
 class AutoCompleteEvent extends Event {


      /**
       * @Event("Symfony\Contracts\EventDispatcher\Event")
       */
      public const SEARCH = 'autocomplete.search';


      protected $term;

      /**
        * {@inheritdoc}
        */
      public function __construct($term) {
          $this->term = $term;
      }

      /**
        * @returns string term
        */
      public function getTerm() {
          return $this->term;
      }

  }

//formType
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options):void {


        $this->dispatcher->addListener(AutoCompleteEvent::SEARCH,function(AutoCompleteEvent $event){
            dd("foo",$event);
        });
    }

//searchController
public function defaultCompleter(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em,EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher,$entityName){


        $event = new AutoCompleteEvent("toto");
        $dispatcher->dispatch($event, AutoCompleteEvent::SEARCH);

}

It seems EventListener can execute itself from the formType so I can have access to formType options. From what I understand eventSubscribers don't have this context of execution.
In the profiler :
searchController : the event is Orphaned
FormType : the event is registred but not called

The problem is that, in your current setup, the listener is only listening to events during "buildForm", I'm not entirely sure if what you're trying to accomplish is possible using EventSubscribers or EventListeners (but I could obviously be very wrong!). Without JavaScript making requests to some AJAX endpoint "onchange", a form field with a listener attached to it won't do anything whilst the user is typing as there is no Request the listener can hook into (there's no communication with the server). I would suggest looking into: https://ux.symfony.com/autocomplete

Hi, I did used ux and i based my new componant on the same lib. I also did some ajax request that call the searchcontroller when user is typing to trigger the event but as you said it : the listener only listen during the build form. Thank for your answer.. I switch to another method
